# Is the military the US military or Canadian military?

Tags: orphan-black

The show *Orphan Black* is a Canadian production and most of the show and its characters and organizations were based in Canada (more specifically Toronto and the surrounding areas).

But was the military the US military or Canadian military?

They weren't very explicit about this, but there were sometimes US flags and also references to "Arlington" (which in US movies/shows would usually be referring to Arlington, Virginia).

Comment: Which episode are you referring to?

Comment: @Paulie_D: Almost all episodes in S02 and S03 (and many episodes in the other seasons too) make at least some reference to the military.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where the show takes place is [deliberately ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_Black#Location), and the Orphan Black military uniforms often have no identifying marks, but I believe that when they do they are always US military. For example, the [soldiers holding Helena](https://ew.com/article/2014/06/21/orphan-black-tatiana-maslany-season-finale/) in the Season 2 finale have "US Army" chest tags and [beret flashes](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Beret_flash_of_the_United_States_Army.svg). Paul has a reversed [US flag shoulder patch](https://ew.com/article/2014/06/21/orphan-black-creators-season-finale-burning-questions/). It is, of course, possible that elements of both the US and Canadian military could be working together.

Comment: Also: (1) In many episodes of S03, they are at a "Rendition Camp" (black site, probably in Mexico), where they have no identifying marks. (2) In S03E10, Virginia Rhoady is in a building with soldiers and two US flags. (3) I did not ever notice any Canadian flags associated with soldiers.